# How to extract multiple attributes of a object chosen by user through mat-options (drop down list) in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, dropdown

**TLDR: dropdown list is a list of objects. Not sure how to capture multiple  attributes of chosen object.**

**What I currently have working:**

I have a simple dropdown list that displays the details of a returned obj through API call:

```
 <mat-form-field class="testSection">
        <mat-label>Available Test Results:</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="testName" name="testName" ngDefaultControl>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let test of tests" [value]="test.testName">
            {{ test.testName + test.testType + test.results + test.cohortId}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

where on my component.ts, I have a testName defined as a string:

```
testName: string
```

Through this, i am indeed able to retrieve the correct `test.testName` based on what user chooses in the dropDown list (based on the specific `test` clicked by user)

**What I need:**

**I want to extend this further.** Lets say I want **both** `test.name` and `test.results` and assign them to variables `testName` and `testResults` for use in a further API call. How do i go about doing this?

I've tried changing `[value]="test.testName"` to `[value]="test.testName, test.testResults"`
and `[(ngModel)]="testMap"` where testMap is defined in component as: `testMap: Map<string, string>`.

This unfortunately did nothing and i just end up capturing only test.testName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply bind your `[(ngModel)]` variable to be the entire test object. Like this:

```
 <mat-form-field class="testSection">
        <mat-label>Available Test Results:</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="testObject" name="testName" ngDefaultControl>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let test of tests" [value]="test">
            {{ test.testName + test.testType + test.results + test.cohortId}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

I only changed two parts of your code

(1) The variable binded with `[(ngModel)]`

(2) `[value]="test.testName"` to  `[value]="test"`.

You'll need to create a new member variable in your component called `testObject` which you will be able to use to access any attribute of your selected value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how should i define the testObject? Do I have to define it to fit exactly the type and attributes of the test? ie. in this case test is really just a java model(on the backend) with attributes testName, testResults ... etc. And how do I access the attribute on the component side?

Comment: To add on to my previous comment, I created a new model with all the indentical attributes and now it works. thanks!

Comment: The easy way to do it would just define it's type to be any like so `testObject: any;`. But it may be better to create an interface defining all of it's attributes. In your `.ts` file you can simply do things like `console.log(testObject.testName)`. Hope that clears things up for you.